# Adding new strings line by line from a file to a new one

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data output file in the format below from the script I run.

```
1. xxx %percentage1
2. yyy %percentage1
.
.
.
```

I am trying to take the percentages only, and append them to the same formatted file line by line (writing a new file once in the process).

```
1. xxx %percentage1 %percentage2
2. yyy %percentage1 %percentage2
```

The main idea is every time I run the code with a source data file I want it to add those percentages to the new file line by line.

```
1. xxx %percentage1 %percentage2 %percentage3 ...
2. yyy %percentage1 %percentage2 %percentage3 ...
```

This is what I could come up with:

```
import os

os.chdir("directory")

f = open("data1", "r")

n=3

a = f.readlines()
b = []

for i in range(n):
    b.append(a[i].split(" ")[2])

file_lines = []

with open("data1", 'r') as f:
    for t in range(n):
        for x in f.readlines():
            file_lines.append(''.join([x.strip(), b[t], '\n']))
            print(b[t])

with open("data2", 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(file_lines)
```

With this code I get the new file but the appending percentages are all from the first line, not different for each line. And I can only get one set of percentages added only and it is overwriting it rather than adding more down the lines.

I hope I explained it properly, if you can give some help I would be glad.

Comment: you must read both files simultaneously. And then append the line of the first file to the line of the second file. But you cannot write the resulting line to the second file. So you need a third file that holds the output of file1+file2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dict as a structure to load and write your data. This dict can then be pickled to store the data.

EDIT: added missing return statement

EDIT2: Fix return list of get_data

```py
import pickle
import os

output = 'output'
dump = 'dump'
output_dict = {}
if os.path.exists(dump):
    with open(dump, 'rb') as f:
        output_dict = pickle.load(f)

def read_data(lines):
    """ Builds a dict from a list of lines where the keys are
    a tuple(w1, w2) and the values are w3 where w1, w2 and w3
    are the 3 words composing each line.
    """
    d = {}
    for line in lines:
        elts = line.split()
        assert(len(elts)==3)
        d[tuple(elts[:2])] = elts[2]
    return d

def get_data(data):
    """ Recover data from a dict as a list of strings.
    The formatting for each element of the list is the following:
    k[0] k[1] v
    where k and v are the key/values of the data dict.
    """
    lines = []
    for k, v in data.items():
        line = list(k)
        line += [v, '\n'] 
        lines.append(' '.join(line))
    return lines

def update_data(output_d, new_d):
    """ Update a data dict with new data
    The values are appended if the key already exists.
    Otherwise a new key/value pair is created.
    """
    for k, v in new_d.items():
        if k in output_d:
            output_d[k] = ' '.join([output_d[k], v])
        else:
            output_d[k] = v

for data_file in ('data1', 'data2', 'data3'):
    with open(data_file) as f:
        d1 = read_data(f.readlines())
    update_data(output_dict, d1)

print("Dumping data", output_dict)
with open(dump, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(output_dict, f)
print("Writing data")
with open(output, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(get_data(output_dict)))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems this is really close to the solution. However I am getting this error:

`Dumping data {('1.', 'xxx'): '82% 55% 44%', ('2.', 'yyy'): '6% 2% 3%', ('3.', 'zzz'): '1% 2% 4%'}
Writing data

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 59, in <module>
    f.write(' '.join(get_data(output_dict)))
TypeError: can only join an iterable`

Comment: I forgot a return statement in `get_data`. I edited my answer.

Comment: This time:

`f.write(' '.join(get_data(output_dict)))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

My test input are three files named data1,2,3 with following content:

`1. xxx 82/55/44%
2. yyy 6/2/3%
3. zzz 1/2/4%`

I am trying to fix as well. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, i fixed the code. In the first version I tested, `get_data` was not returning anything and wrote the lines into the file. I changed this without proper testing. This should work now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I also managed to make it work with a For loop at the last step:

`with open(output, 'w') as f:
    for i in get_data(output_dict):
        for j in i:
            f.write(' ' + j)`